# Make certain numbers inputted by the user sub/sup-string

Tags: javascript, string, properties, string-matching

I have a code, where the user can input some text and when they press the button the text will get insertet further down on the page for later use.

But before it goes down there I'd like to make certain numbers subscript, or supscript if they type "_" or "^" before the number.

My code looks something like this:

```js
function moveText() {
  var string = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var node = document.createTextNode(string);
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  para.appendChild(node);
  var element = document.getElementById("output");
  element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE HTML >
<body>
  <div>
    <!-- I have included an example of what a user might write -->
    <input type="text" id="input" value="1 _2 3 _4 ^5">
    <input type="button" value="insert" onclick="moveText()">
  </div>
  <div id="output">
    <!-- This is where the text goes when the button is pressed -->
    <!-- When the text goes here I'd like all numbers following a "_" to be subscript and "^" to be supscript -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: @hindmost I see how this is usefull. But I don't see how to implement it. The best way i can come up with on the top of my head is to make each character it's own element, and then arrange them like that which to me seems like a lot to do.

Comment: _make each character it's own element._ Bingo! Now you see how to implement

Comment: But how do I detect which ones to make top and bottom?

Comment: As you wrote yourself,  `_`/`^` before a number should indicate subscript/superscript

Comment: I'm not intirely sure how to write the js though...